# Monogame: GamePadState constructor

Tags: c#, monogame

can anyone explain what the constructors for GamePadState are doing under the hood, so to speak. I've looked online and can't find much that I understand.

I thought maybe you could create a custom GamePadState to use as a comparison template but maybe not?

If I could see the written code I could probably figure some of it out.

Any help appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: You can look at the [Monogame Source Code](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame) on GitHub, here is the file for [GamePadState.cs](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/9f3a8356f326d4380d022ca30cd6b16afe14d520/MonoGame.Framework/Input/GamePadState.cs)

Comment: This is a really bad idea, what if your player has changed the layout ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the GamePadState.cs file that Ron Beyer linked to in a comment you will see that the GamePadState constructors are simply setting the initial state of the various buttons, triggers, and thumbsticks.

You could indeed create a new gamepad state and pass in the state of all the buttons, triggers, etc. in order to use it as a comparison.

```
var thumbSticks = new GamePadThumbSticks(new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 0));
var triggers = new GamePadTriggers(0, 1);
var buttons = new GamePadButtons(Buttons.A);
var dPad = new GamePadDPad(ButtonState.Released, ButtonState.Pressed, ButtonState.Released, ButtonState.Released);

var cState = new GamePadState(thumbSticks, triggers, buttons, dPad);
var cState2 = GamePadState.Default;

Console.WriteLine(cState == cState2); //false
```

However if you try and compare a constructed GamePadState with one obtained from a GamePad then they will never be equal as the `PacketNumber` won't match

A simple solution is to create an extension method that compares the two states without evaluating the `PacketNumber`:

```
public static bool Compare(this GamePadState g1, GamePadState g2)
{
    return (g1.IsConnected == g2.IsConnected &&
        g1.Buttons == g2.Buttons &&
        g1.DPad == g2.DPad &&
        g1.ThumbSticks == g2.ThumbSticks &&
        g1.Triggers == g2.Triggers);
}
```

usage: `gamePadState1.Compare(gamePadState2);`

(Your question was a little vague on what 'Comparison Template' meant so this all may be overkill but I hope it answered your question)